# Retrieve data from tables via JOINS

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have three tables: `sessions`, `urls` and `visitors`.
I need to join these three tables in such a way that I should be able to get data from each table and the maximum number of rows returned should be equal to sessions.

Following is the basic schema of my tables.

Table `sessions`

```
session_id | url_id | referrer_id | country
-------------------------------------------
  1234     |  a1b1  |    bb11     |   US
  4567     |  x1y1  |    ll33     |   IN
  6789     |  a1b1  |    ff99     |   UK
```

Table `urls`

```
  id       |        url                 |
-----------------------------------------
 a1b1      | https://url-1.com          |
 x1y1      | https://url-2.com          |
 bb11      | https://referrer-url-1.com |
 ll33      | https://referrer-url-2.com |
 ff99      | https://referrer-url-3.com |
```

Table `visitors`

```
   id      | session_id | visiting_time |
-----------------------------------------
   1       |   1234     |   447383930   |
   2       |   4567     |   547383930   |
   3       |   6789     |   647383930   |
```

What I want as the **final output should look like**:

```
 session_id | visiting_time | url                |  referrer_url      | country
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1234     |  447383930    | https://url-1.com  | https://referrer-url-1.com | US |
   4567     |  547383930    | https://url-2.com  | https://referrer-url-2.com | IN |
   6789     |  647383930    | https://url-1.com  | https://referrer-url-3.com | UK |
```

I want to map `url_id` in `sessions` table with `id` in `urls` table and get the corresponding `url` from `urls` table and have the value in the new column named `url`. Similarly, map `referrer_id` in `sessions` table with `id` in `urls` table and get the corresponding `url` from `urls` table and have the value in the new column named `referring_url`.

As you can see: JOINS with `sessions` and `visitors` is simple and can be simply done via:

```
select session_id, visiting_time, country
from sessions,
     visitors
where sessions.session_id = visitors.session_id;
```

But joining with `urls` table and getting the `url` and `referring_url` is somewhat tricky. I have tried `LEFT JOIN` and `INNER JOIN` but couldn't make it work.

Any help with query or references would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Please stop using comma based Implicit joins and use [Explicit `Join` based syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins)

Comment: Your current query does an INNER JOIN, an old style implicit one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You should avoid using comma based Implicit joins and use [Explicit `Join` based syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins)
- You will need two joins with `urls` table; one to fetch the `url` and another for `referrer_url`.

Try the following:

```
SELECT s.session_id, 
       v.visiting_time, 
       u1.url, 
       u2.url AS referrer_url, 
       s.country
FROM sessions AS s
JOIN visitors AS v ON v.session_id = s.session_id 
JOIN urls AS u1 ON u1.id = s.url_id 
JOIN urls AS u2 ON u2.id = s.referrer_id
```

Comment: All other answers are also valid but this answer worked perfectly and was answered first. Thanks Madhur Bhaiya for helping :)

Comment: @softvar happy to help; and do stop using comma based joins :)

Comment: Sure, will take care from next timw. Will read more about it in depth.

Answer (score 1):

```
select sessions.session_id, visitors.visiting_time, urls.url, urlsReferrer.url referrer_url, sessions.country
from sessions
        inner join visitors on sessions.session_id = visitors.session_id
        inner join urls on sessions.url_id = url.id
        left join urls urlsReferrer on sessions.referrer_id = urlsReferrer.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a join on urls twice one of url_id and one for referrer_id

```
    select session_id
      , visiting_time
      , u1.url
      , u2.url
      , country
    from sessions
    INNER JOIN  visitors ON sessions.session_id = visitors.session_id
    INNER JOIN urls u1 on u1.id= sessions.url_id
    INNER JOIN urls u2 on u2.id= sessions.referrer_id
```

In this way you can join the sessions for retrive both then values  you need

Answer (score 1):

Joins are defined in the from statement - please read up on https://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp to better get a sense of join usage.

Modify the query as needed based on which table "referrer_url" actually comes from

**Warning:** You must include a where statement which limits your result. I strongly suggest defining a date field and range to prevent you from initiating a long running query and affecting database performance.

### see below for query

```
select 
s.session_id, 
v.visiting_time, 
s.country,
u.url,
u.referrer_url


from 
sessions s
join visitors v on session_id
join urls on u.id=s.url_id

;
```